# probability question convergence

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, ergodic-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space.

Define an rv such that $X_n=1$ with $\mathbb{P}(X_n=1)=1$ and 0 with $\mathbb{P}(X_n=0)=0$ for all n.

Then, $X_n\rightarrow 1$ in $\mathbb{P}$

I am confused as to how to prove this. I am aware that we must show that

$\mathbb{P}(|X_n-1|>\epsilon)\rightarrow 0$ and $n\rightarrow \infty$ but i'm having issues in constructing suitable cases.

Attempt:

Let $0<\epsilon<1$ then

$\{$ $X_n=0$ $\}$ $=$ $\{$ $|X_n-1|>\epsilon$ $\}$

thus, $\mathbb{P}(X_n=0 )=\mathbb{P}(|X_n-1|>\epsilon)=0$

is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct (unless $X_n$'s take other values with probability $0$. In that case your first line is wrong but the next line is correct.

Comment: why is my first line wrong? may you write a proof without first line?

Comment: It is not explcitly mentioned that $0$ and $1$ are the only values of $X_n$. We may have $X_n=2$ for some sample points, but certainly $P(X_n=2)$ would then be $0$. So the set theoretic equation $\{X_n=0\}=\{|X_n-1| >\epsilon\}$ may be false.

Comment: okay so just to reiterate, if $X_n$ only takes in values 0 and 1 then my proof is correct? even with $0<\epsilon<1$?

Comment: Yes, it is perfect in that case.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy okay, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore $\mathbb{P}(X_n=0)$ then your proof could become:

For all $\epsilon >0$ you have

$0 \le \mathbb{P}(|X_n-1|>\epsilon) \le \mathbb{P}(|X_n -1| \not=0) = 1-\mathbb{P}(X_n=1)=1-1=0$

so $\mathbb{P}(|X_n-1|>\epsilon) =0$